# GAS' replaceText and javascript's String.replace

Tags: javascript, string, replace, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Does anyone know if google-apps-script's `replaceText` function internally uses javascript's `String.replace` function?

The reason I'm asking is that [google-apps-script's `replaceText` function's syntax](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText%28String,String%29) is:

```
replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)
```

Where as [javascript's `String.replace` function's syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is:

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[,   flags]);
```

I.e., the replacement can be either a string or a function.

All in all, can I use function as the replacement in google-apps-script's `replaceText` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. it does not. The `replacement` has to be a string. Another important difference is that even though `searchPattern` is a string, it will create a regexp to do the matching. It's not like `String.replace` where you can provide a literal string or a regexp.

You could write your own `replaceText` function that uses String.replace "internally". You'd just have to loop the entire document structure looking for [Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) blocks and do it.